# What does "enhabitation" mean?

Tags: meaning

I saw that word in an article more than once. When I saw it for the first time, I thought it might be "inhabitation", but the repeating of that word convinced me that it was not a mistake. I could not find it in any dictionary. Is there a meaning of "enhabitation" or can it be some kind of term?

> Through a process of routine-formation, remembering occurs without conscious awarenes. This process might be called enhabiation: 'thoughts reactions and symbols become turned into routine habits and, thus, they become enhabited' (Billig 1995:42)

"Reproducing the Nation: Banal Nationalism in the Turkish Press", Media, Culture & Society, Vol. 22: 787-804.

[image: The article: "Reproducing the Nation: Banal Nationalism in the Turkish Press", Media, Culture & Society, Vol. 22: 787-804.]

Comment: Please provide a clear citation of the source.  Ideally a link to the original.  If a link is not possible then provide lots of context. As you note this is "not in the dictionary" which means that it is a not a standard part of English.  It is probably an old form of inhabitation but we can't say for certain without the citation and the context.

Comment: I think we can answer this in a way that is helpful for learning English, not just as a substitute for a dictionary. I'll give it a try right now.

Comment: Thanks for your interests. I added a photo of the paragraph in which the word was used three times and waiting for your answers. Thank you.

Comment: @BenKovitz No you couldn't You needed to find the source.  You searched on google books, which is great. But this question needed a source.  I thank the OP for providing one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [search on Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22enhabitation%22)* reveals that *enhabitation* is a word coined by the sociologist [Michael Billig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Billig).

Here are the thoughts that go through my mind as a fluent speaker when I see this new and unfamiliar word. (I wrote this before the paragraph with the context was added to the question. That paragraph removes the need to guess, but I think it helps a lot to see how a fluent speaker makes an educated guess about a new word.)

1. Is it a mistake for "inhabitation"? If it's deliberate, then someone probably invented it by drawing upon classical roots,* as is usual when making technical terminology. So, it's probably an obscure technical term.
2. The prefixes **in-** and **en-** both come from Latin **in**. **En-** is the French version, as in **entrench**, **enfeeble**, **enable**, etc. In English, we often choose **en-** instead of **in-** when coining a new word to mean "become" or "make" instead of "be inside". Or, it *could* be an obsolete French spelling.
3. The word **habitus** has previously been brought from [Latin](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/habitus#Etymology_2_2), where it means mode of dress as well as habit or the general condition of something (as in "a nun's [habit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religious_habit)"), into [English](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/habitus#English) scientific terminology, to mean things like an organism's overall way of life, a person's typical stance or demeanor, the common traits or beliefs or behaviors of a social group, and similar things.

If the context is sociology, I would guess that enhabitation is the process of acquiring the attitudes, manner of dress, etc. of a social group, by participation in life among that social group, so that they become unconscious, effortless, and feel like being yourself rather than a deliberate act or choice. The word could also mean the result of that process, as often happens with **-tion** words.

Indeed it appears that Billig coined the verb **enhabit** for the process of picking up a society's habitus. Most likely he means something more specific than the general guess that the roots suggest.

There are two lessons here for someone learning English:

1. If you can recognize roots of the word, like **habit**, look at their etymologies. Etymologies often provide clues to how people will draw upon the older, stabler meanings of roots to coin new words. [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/habit#Etymology_1) makes this easy, since you can just follow the links to the classical root words, and from there follow the links to the English words that derive from them.
2. [Google Books](https://books.google.com/) is one of the best places to search to see how a word or phrase is actually used, especially in formal writing. Real usage goes far beyond what dictionaries can document, of course.

---

* <sub>That is, words from Latin and Ancient Greek.</sub>

Comment: +many! Note that Billig is cited in the passage OP added.

Comment: @StoneyB Aww, that takes the sport out of it. ;) I just added a note to clarify that the passage makes the guesswork unnecessary.

Comment: @BenKovitz What does "takes  the sport out of it" mean?

Comment: @dan I only meant it as a joke, but it means to make it so easy that it's no longer "sporting"—that is, difficult enough to present a challenge, as if figuring out the meaning of "enhabitation" were a sport where we want to make a "fair" contest against the word's attempt to keep its meaning unknown. More examples on [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q="takes+the+sport+out+of+it"&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A%2Ccd_max%3A2015&tbm=bks).

Answer (score 2):

The author makes it clear (*might be called*) that this is a fairly novel term. Its meaning and source are provided right in the passage you quote:

> Through a process of *routine-formation*, remembering occurs without conscious awareness.
>
> "Thoughts, reactions, and symbols become turned into *routine habits* and, thus, they become *enhabited*' (BIllig, 1995:42).

The prefix *en-* is often employed in a causative or motive sense: cause something to 'enter' a particular state. Compare *enclose*, *endanger*, *encode*.

Answer (score -1):

The word Enhabit has the same meaning as Inhabit. Just that it is an obsolete form of the word Inhabit.It is a verb and French word borrowed from the French word "Enhabiter" which is equally obsolete.